# Concatenate files with a specific naming pattern (unix)

Tags: loops, unix, concatenation, sh, string-matching

I want to concatenate files which follow a specific name pattern, i.e. I have many files like:

```
nameX_4_1.txt
nameX_983_2.txt
nameX_5_1.txt
nameX_2_2.txt
nameY_7_1.txt
nameY_4_2.txt
nameY_8_1.txt
nameY_3_2.txt
nameY_9_1.txt
nameY_6_2.txt
.
.
.
```

...and I want to concatenate always the files, which have the same "name?" and the same last number (either 1 or 2), i.e. from the example files above to concatenate

```
"nameX_4_1.txt" and "nameX_5_1.txt"  
"nameX_983_2.txt" and "nameX_2_2.txt"
"nameY_7_1.txt" and "nameY_8_1.txt" and "nameY_9_1.txt"
"nameY_4_2.txt" and "nameY_3_2.txt" and "nameY_6_2.txt"
.
.
.
```

I first tried to write a script like:

```
for f1 in *_?_1.txt
do
f2="${f1%%_?_1.txt}_?_2.txt"
.
.
.
```

...but I relized (being a complete unix rookie) that this is not the way how to get the name of the other matching files so then the files of selected names can be concatenated in loop...
I would be thankfull for any hints (preferentially using unix commands but I'm actually opened to any other solution). Thanks!

Comment: What should be the name of the concatenated files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the edit!

First, sorry for a mistake before. I don't know what has gotten into me of late.

Second, question doesn't specify how would you like to concatenate files.

If by tagging it with Unix you wanted to do it in shell (Bash for example), well, this will get you what you wanted:

```
#! /bin/bash

for file in $(ls ./name*1.txt)
do
    echo $file
done
```

This will print out all files (one per each line) filtering them by wildcard (using '*' in name).
You will have to use read command or cat with a lot of piping to concatenate content of files whose names will be in $file variable.

If you have many files this will be a bit inpractical. It will still work but it is rude toward your system.

Therefore I recommend you to use some real scripting language to achieve what you want in one process.
Here's a complete example in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import glob

namepattern = "./name*1.txt"
outputfile = "./output.txt"
whole_text = ""
for x in glob.iglob(namepattern):
    f = open(x, "r")
    whole_text += "\n"+f.read()
    f.close()
f = open(outputfile, "w")
f.write(whole_text)
f.close()
```

If you want to ensure that your files are sorted before concatenation add sorted() to for loop:

```
for x in sorted(glob.iglob(...)): ...
```

This though will concatenate only one group of files, specified by the namepattern variable. So you will have to run this script few times. One of ideas on how to group them is presented here by hansaplast.

Comment: you should state that this is python

Comment: What does this even have to do with the question? It's a random code snippet with no explanation; it's in a different (unspecified) programming language; it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys! Somehow saw Python in tags. Very well, I'l edit!

Answer (score 1):

As a start point, you can try this (bash):

```
for xy in X Y; do 
  for s12 in 1 2; do 
    echo "   $xy --- $s12"
    for file in $(ls name${xy}_*_$s12.txt); do
      echo "file $file"
    done
  done
done
```

Note the first `echo` line: it is printed before each group of file. Instead of this `echo` you can choose (prepare) to write to a temporary file, or build a command to be executed later. For a temporary file, instead of `echo file $file` you would do `cat $file >> my_temporary_file`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you're open to any programming languages here is a python solution:

```python
import os
from collections import defaultdict

buckets = defaultdict(list)

for filename in os.listdir('files/'):
    parts = filename.split('.')[0]('_')
    # group by string before first _ and number after last _
    # "nameX_4_1.txt" becomes ("nameX", "1")
    key = (parts[0], parts[-1]) 
    buckets[key].append(filename)

# files are now grouped, output them (order is not predictable)
for key,value in buckets.items():
    print(", ".join(value))
```

Sample session:

```
$ ls files/
nameX_2_2.txt   nameX_5_1.txt   nameY_3_2.txt   nameY_6_2.txt   nameY_8_1.txt
nameX_4_1.txt   nameX_983_2.txt nameY_4_2.txt   nameY_7_1.txt   nameY_9_1.txt

$ python script.py
nameX_2_2.txt, nameX_983_2.txt
nameY_3_2.txt, nameY_4_2.txt, nameY_6_2.txt
nameY_7_1.txt, nameY_8_1.txt, nameY_9_1.txt
nameX_4_1.txt, nameX_5_1.txt
```

The python program expects the files to be in `files/` so you would need to change that to the actual directory.

Please comment if you'd like to know more about what the python program does or if you miss any features.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks a bit hairy, so I'd probably use perl, not shell (warning, untested code):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %groups;

for my $file (glob '*_*_[12].txt') {
    my $key = $file;
    $key =~ s/_[^_]*(?=_\d\.txt\z)/_X/ or die "No match for $key";
    push @{$groups{$key}}, $file;
}

for my $group (values %groups) {
    print "@$group\n";
}
```

The idea is to loop over all files matching `*_*_[12].txt` and compute a normalized key for each name; e.g. `foobar_123_1.txt` would become `foobar_X_1.txt` (we replace the part between the last two underscores with `X`).

This way all the files that you want to concatenate are grouped together under the same key. At the end we simply loop over all groups and output the filenames (separated by a space) in each group, followed by a newline.